# Take a portion of equirectangular image or video to fit in a-plane

Tags: textures, aframe

I'd like to create a tiny preview of a 360 image or video in a-frame, placing it in a a-plane, but showing just a portion of the texture, instead of the equirectangular one; could you give me some hints on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the repeat and offset property of the material, and set repeat to less than 1, which will scale the image larger than the plane, effectively cropping it.

[docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#standard)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've tried :

'  repeat: 0.5, offset: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}  '

but all i see, is something like this: https://imgur.com/LwZvoGO .

Apparently the repeat value works, so maybe I'm using offset wrong, is that correct?

Comment: repeat takes 2 params, x and y. By entering only 1 param, y becomes 0. use this `repeat: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}`